# Doesn't zend openid auto clean nonce files?

Tags: zend-framework, openid, nonce

I am using zend OpenID library:https://github.com/marcinwol/zfopenid  works great. But, the issue is not cleaning tmp folder files[nonce files]. It seems purgeNonces members of Zend_OpenId_Consumer_Storage_File are
not being called anywhere in the execution.  http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.openid.consumer.html dbstorage seems to clear the expired data. But, that too is not clearing Nonce. I am planning to use dbstorage. Any examples would be appreciated.
Thanks

I found some info, we do not need to delete discovery files as it is for single id.
http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#verify_nonce
as per this, Zend_OpenId_Consumer_Storage_File doesn't delete nonce files. Whenever we want to call purgeNonce, we must use
"The time-stamp MAY be used to reject responses that are too far away from the current time".so I can delete old nonce files.
Also, dbstorage example's isUniqueNonce has to check for a duplicate nonce for the same OP, Not for all OP.
please correct my understanding if it is wrong.